# Is Terracota Cluster still opensource?

Tags: cluster-computing, terracotta

and if yes, where it could be found?!
According to [this](http://www.infoq.com/news/2006/12/terracotta-jvm-clustering) infoq entry, they have opensourced it. But right now, there is not such a product in their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page, http://terracotta.org/dl/oss-download-catalog , has the links to the opensource version of terracotta and related products.  You may be presented with a page requiring you to register prior to the download.  I tried downloading from there yesterday, and I was able to successfully download terracotta and get it running locally.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:
[Terracota Source Repository](http://www.terracotta.org/confluence/display/wiki/Source+Repository)