# Where to download Terracotta

Tags: spring, hibernate, terracotta

I am completely new to Terracotta and trying to understand it by following an example given in this post - [Integrating Terracotta EHCache for Hibernate with Spring PetClinic](http://javathink.blogspot.in/2010/01/tutorial-integrating-terracotta-ehcache.html)

I was able to download and make the Sprin's petclinic application up and running but I am stuck on what software to download for terracotta as given in Step 4:

> Step 4 - Install Terracotta
>
> Download Terracotta from the http://www.terracotta.org/download. Unzip
>   and install into $TC_HOME

I went to [terracotta site](http://www.terracotta.org/downloads) and got confused on what software I need to download for working on the example that I am following.

I followed the SO post for [Is Terracota Cluster still opensource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551671/is-terracota-cluster-still-opensource) and registered myself with terracotta and then again I see multiple softwares available for download in [Terracotta site](http://terracotta.org/downloads/open-source/catalog)

Please help me on what is the software I need to download for this example.

Comment: Can some please help me on what software needs to be downloaded, as I am new to terracotta and I see so many listed in terracotta site?

Answer (score 2):

Once you are on the [Terracotta Open Source download page](http://terracotta.org/downloads/open-source/catalog), what you want is the link inside section `Terracotta Server Array` which points to the `terracotta-{version}.tar.gz` archive.

Note that registration is not mandatory and can be skipped - see `X` icon on top right of the registration form.